# OAuthWebsecurity mvc4 Facebook login with email failing on deployment

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I used the code of **"FacebookScopedClient"** mentioned in this [link](http://yassershaikh.com/using-facebook-login-with-asp-net-mvc-4/)
The same code is mentioned in multiple answers on stackoverflow too, and i actually got the code from stackoverflow but i don't remember from where i got. So, i linked to this article. This code need some little improvement to work with facebook's api v2, because username in scope is now depricated.

**Issue** which i was facing, because of which i used this code, was that i was trying **to get email of facebook account in mvc4** and i could not find anyplace to mention scope in default client of mvc4. 
So, using this client i got the required information but, as written in comments of this article, **this is working only on localhost**, in deployment server i get in callback method and on calling **AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();** i get isSuccessful property false and Error null (I tested it by printing the values in hidden fields).
So, the question is if it is possible to get user email in mvc4 without using this client, what is it. And if not, than what is the issue and how to resolve it to get it to work in production environment. I read something about time, i suspect that might be the issue, because my server is in different time zone. But i don't know how to be sure and how to solve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22622149 testing this solution, will update you, seems like my question is a duplicate. Will update here.

Comment: yes this solved the problem, and this question is duplicate :D